# boost thread & class

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, boost

I need to execute "Run" in a separate thread

```
class TcpClient
{
public:
    TcpClient();
    virtual ~TcpClient();

    void Run();
}
```

I run it using boost:

```
    MessageBox(0, "1", APP_NAME, NULL);
    TcpClient client;
    boost::thread thread( boost::bind( &TcpClient::Run, &client) );
    thread.join();
    MessageBox(0, "2", APP_NAME, NULL);
```

Run method:

```
void TcpClient::Run()
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10000) ); //Sleep 10 sec
}
```

Messageboks2 must be called immediately after the first, but I have to wait 10 seconds. Where there may be a mistake?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need `bind` here; the `thread` constructor has all that mechanism built in, so all you need is `std::thread thr(&TcpClient::Run, &client);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you call `join` in the thread immediately after you create it. It blocks until the thread is done.

Either don't call `join` (it will be done by the destructor when the variable goes out of scope) or [detach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.detac) the thread.

---

As noted by [Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker), the destructor will **not** join the thread, instead it will call `terminate` which terminates the whole process. To ensure that `join` is called on a Boost thread, use a [`thread_joiner`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.destructor2) class.

Comment: In C++11, if you don't call `join` and you don't call `detach`, the destructor will call `terminate`. I assume Boost does the same. There was an early specification where the destructor called `join`, but that was changed.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're correct. And even the version 1 of Boost thread didn't actually join the thread, it just detached it.